# java System.setProperty not affecting anti-aliasing; command line option works

Tags: java, swing, system-properties

I'm trying to make a java Swing program default to anti-aliasing when run on Linux.  It works when I pass the settings as command line options or using _JAVA_OPTIONS, but not using System.setProperty().

I'm using Java SE 6 on Centos 5.5 via VNC with gnome metacity WM.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("useSystemAAFontSettings", "lcd");
        System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JButton button = new JButton("Button");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any clues what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

PS: The swing.aatext setting seems to have no effect in any case, but I included it as I saw it as part of the solution elsewhere.

Comment: I think it has to do with when the property is set and accessed. When it is on the CLI or JAVA_OPTS, it is set prior to program execution, here you are already in the main method so the app has started and that property is accessed only on app start.

Comment: Probably because the setting is `awt.useSystemAAFontSetting` and not simply `useSystemAAFontSettings`.

Comment: @Guillaume: Oops, that's a typo above.  I have it correct in my code and same results.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @tinker: Thanks; that makes sense.  So, does that mean that (a) all the recommendations to do this are just plain wrong, and (b) it's impossible to turn on anti-aliasing globally for the application, programmatically?

Comment: a) Can you be specific about the recommendations you are talking about? b) I believe so, but I cannot guarantee it - I don't have very deep knowledge on this topic.

Comment: Aha.  The line was right in my code but wrong in the test program.  Fixing it in the test program fixed the test program.  In my actual program, I moved the statement into my main() and it now works.  I find that a bit odd because it didn't move much at all; it still preceded the creation of the jFrame.

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).