# Add an image with JLabel without loss of quality

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

so I just started learning Java (have some C++ experience) and I'm having some trouble. I never created a GUI, so I'm experimenting with it right now, while learning Java at the same time. The issue I have right now is that I can't figure out a way how to add an image with JLabel without loss of quality. Every method I tried, using Graphics 2D, Thumbnailator, BufferedImage gets me the same result. It feels like image loses it's sharpness from the original one.

I have looked for solutions, I really did, but most of them are really old or really hard to understand. So, I'm asking for help where, if you can, explain it to me like I'm five.

This is how I import an image right now, as it seems like the easiest method.

```
ImageIcon logo = new 
ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("logo.png"));

    logoLabel.setIcon(logo);
    logoLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(logo.getIconWidth(), 
    logo.getIconHeight()));
```

But I'm sure there are other methods. Thanks for the help in advance.

I'm on Windows 11 Home 22H2, using IntelliJ Community Edition 232.10203.10 with Java 11.0.20

Full code:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUI implements ActionListener {

    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;
    public GUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Click me");
        label = new JLabel("Number of clicks: 0");
        panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("logo.png"));
        Dimension buttonDim = new Dimension(100, 40);

        logoLabel.setIcon(logo);

        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setPreferredSize(buttonDim);

        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(logoLabel);

        frame.setSize(1100, 900);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Our GUI");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of clicks: " + count);
    }
}
```

Original image:

[image]

What I get in the GUI

[image]

I'm not resizing it or anything.

Comment: Start by getting rid of `logoLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(logo.getIconWidth(), logo.getIconHeight()));` - it's otherwise irrelevant

Comment: Java won't modify the "quality" of the image and `JLabel` will prefer to show the image at it's full size - which suggests that you're window is smaller then the image and it's then been scaled to fit the area. Consider providing a runnable example

Comment: I use frame.setSize(1000, 800); to set the size of my window. The image is 600x173, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: But I did add the full code and an image I'm using.

Comment: A JLabel will paint the image in its original state. *without loss of quality.* - define loss of quality. Upload your image to this site and upload an image of the frame with the image to this site. Don't use imgur.

Comment: `frame.setSize(1100, 900);` <- use `frame.pack()` instead

Comment: @camickr - added the images.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - but wouldn't I have to set the size of each panel individually then? Because right now, if I use ```frame.pack()```, it makes the smallest window possible and you can't see anything.

Comment: @righN You don't define the size of the components, that's their responsibilities. Take `frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` and move it above `frame.pack`

Comment: What I see is jagged edges on curved and diagonal lines. This seems like an anti-aliasing problem for your OS. Image displays fine on my Windows 11 desktop. Not sure how to check/verify what your desktop is doing. Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039498/java-system-setproperty-not-affecting-anti-aliasing-command-line-option-works will help.

Comment: You should include the Java version. Older versions may have problems with HiDPI displays. Make sure that your os is *not* applying “helpful” compatibility settings.

Comment: @camickr - I'm on Windows 11 too, but I have AMD Ryzen APU and using its iGPU, if that makes a difference? Java version is 11.0.20. I'll check out that link and see if there's any compatibility settings. Thank you!

Comment: After a quick search, I understood IntelliJ set quite an old Java version. Updated it to OpenJDK 21, as that what IntelliJ us using, I think? Going to see other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after updating Java to OpenJDK 21, it still wasn't solved. The real issue actually was with my own system. As I'm using a laptop with QHD screen, it's not comfortable to use it at 100% scaling so I set it to 125%. This was causing the issue. The solution was to add a VM option to the IDE

```
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0
```

This is what worked for me. Thanks everyone for giving ideas on how to solve it!